# opencart get last order id to success page

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce, opencart

is it possible get last order id to order success page.? i just want to  get last order id, so i can set a link to my template file `success.tpl` that link will be go to last order info page..
i had tried something from `controller/checkout/success.php`

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$order_last_id = $this->db->getLastId();
$this->data['order_info'] = $this->url->link('account/order/info', 'order_id=' . $order_last_id,  'SSL');
```

but, bad luck i get url with `0` order id

```
index.php?route=account/order/info&order_id=0
```

any one can help me for get last order id.?

thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` and before this code

```
$this->cart->clear();
```

put

```
$this->data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

Then in your template use an if to test if the `$order_id` isn't empty

```
<?php if(!empty($order_id)): ?>
... CODE HERE using $order ID ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What if you are redirected from 3rd party payment? The session seems to get cleared in that case

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk if thats the case, you can't maintain the order ID. I've never known the session clear from payment gateways. Thats very unlikely

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't edited the core files...

Add just before line 5 of /catalog/controller/checkout/success.php:

```
$this->data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

The problem you have is you're assuming that the user is logged in, and not a guest user, to get around this, check the user is a logged-in user, by adding this to your success.tpl

```
<p><?php echo "Your order ID is "; ?>
<?php if($logged) { ?>
<a href="index.php?route=account/order/info&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $order_id; ?>
<?php if($logged) { ?>
</a>
<?php } ?>
</p>
```

This way, a link is created if they're logged in. If not, it just shows the ID number without the link.

Answer (score 0):

I get orderID for opencart-2.0.3.1 as follows

```
  /*after this this line: $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('order_guest', $activity_data);} */
    $orderID = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```